# How do I add an object to React-Three outside componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I have run the React samples for Three.js, but can't seem to work out how to add an object (mesh, geometry) outside componentDidMount.

I've tried to add new objects, dispose of previous objects, update bufferGeometry

```
componentDidMount() {
  const width = this.mount.clientWidth
  const height = this.mount.clientHeight
  //ADD SCENE
  this.scene = new THREE.Scene()
  //ADD CAMERA
  this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    width / height,
    0.1,
    1000
  )
  this.camera.position.z = 4
  //ADD RENDERER
  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
  this.renderer.setClearColor('#000000')
  this.renderer.setSize(width, height)
  this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
  //ADD CUBE
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(12, 1, 1)
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#FFFF81'     })
  this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  this.scene.add(this.cube)

  this.start()
}

---------------------------------------------
addIT(){
  const geometry3 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(2,3, 1)
  const material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#00FF81'     })
  this.cube3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry3, material3)
  this.scene.add(this.cube3)
  this.start()
}
```

What I'd like to get to is for a react event to be able to add or remove an object from the scene.

At the moment, I get nothing.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually worked out what was happening. Cube3 wasn't being added and an error was being thrown.  I placed a stop render in addIt added the object and then started the render again.